# Drupal 10 Module Overload

Tags: view, drupal, hook, drupal-modules

I am working on Durpal 10, multiple_registration module for creating accounts for journalists and Members.
I would like to overload this module so that I can translate the links: Create new Member account & Create new Journalist account:
Front side:

[front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg8mT.png)

and : [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXWas.png)

Comment: This should be "user interface translation", you can just translate the source strings in the backend or what is your question?